# why would a line of code work when evaluated, but not when run

Tags: dataframe, pycharm, typeerror, evaluate

I have passed a `DataFrame` from an ipython notebook to a function inside a standard `.py` file.

In the function, i'm using `df['column_name'].values` to try to extract all the values from that column.

While debugging (in pycharm), I am running this line in the 'evaluate' tool pycharm provides and it works fine. However, when I run the same line normally (outside the tool window), i get an error:

> "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

When looking at my dataframe in the workspace variables section, it is interpreted correctly as a dataframe.

The dataframe object I am passing has 3 columns ('x','y' and 'likelyhood'), each containing integers/floats. The line in question that unpacks the values inside one of these columns is the first line of the function.

Can anyone explain how this can happen? What is the difference that causes the fact that a line of code can work in one, and return an error in the other?
and also what might cause this specific `TypeError` and how can I solve this bug?

the data frame as printed by df.tail(10):

```
coords  x   y   likelihood
105570  297.497525  332.355521  1.0
105571  297.463208  332.353797  1.0
105572  297.439774  332.383908  1.0
105573  297.457581  332.458205  1.0
105574  297.487260  332.402202  1.0
105575  297.519772  332.451551  1.0
105576  297.495998  332.431064  1.0
105577  297.516722  332.113481  1.0
105578  297.542539  332.080923  1.0
105579  297.528317  332.046282  1.0
```

full function:

```py
    import math  
    import numpy as np  
    import pandas as pd  

    def filter_jumps(bp, thresh=10):  
        """
        the function watches for jumps that cannot happen, and interpolates the location of the point acoordingly  
        """  
        x=bp['x'].values  
        y=bp['y'].values  
        for i in range(1,len(x)):  
            if np.abs(x[i]+y[i]-x[i-1]-y[i-1]) > thresh:  
                start = i-1; end = None; idx=i+1  
                while not end:  
                    if np.abs(x[idx]+y[idx]-x[idx-1]-y[idx-1]) > thresh:  
                        end = idx  
                    else:  
                        idx += 1  
                rang = end-start  
                x[start:end] = np.linspace(x[start], x[end], rang)  
                y[start:end] = np.linspace(y[start], y[end], rang)  
        bp['x'] = x  
        bp['y'] = y  
        return bp
```

Comment: There are literally thousands of reasons why a statement might work all alone, but not when it's integrated in a certain context. It's all about the rest of the code .Which we don't have here ... Could you please add the rest of the code, so that we could help you ?

Comment: can you provide more information on why it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestions. I described the situation further and added the complete function